# Python PANDAS: Conditionally Insert Character in String Field

Tags: python, regex, pandas

What would be the best way to insert a character conditionally in a PANDAS string field with the following criteria:

1. Insert a "." after the first 3 numeric characters from the left (ignore letters)
2. Do not add a "." if there are no additional characters trailing

   ```
   96501
   E0000
   V909
   965
   ```

   Becomes

   ```
   965.01
   E000.0
   V909
   965
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture the first three digits with `((?:\D*\d){3})`, use `(?=.+)` to assert there is at least one more character following, and use back reference to add `.` to the captured pattern:

```
df[0].str.replace(r'^((?:\D*\d){3})(?=.+)', r'\1.')
#0    965.01
#1    E000.0
#2      V909
#3       965
#Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!  If you would not mind, what would also be a version that would count alpha and numeric from the left?

Comment: If both *alpha* and *numeric*, you can use `^((?:[^a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z0-9]){3})(?=.+)`.